# Adding two asynchronous lists, into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I've always found Dictionaries to be an odd thing in python. I know it is just me i'm sure but I cant work out how to take two lists and add them to the dict. If both lists were mapable it wouldn't be a problem something like `dictionary = dict(zip(list1, list2))` would suffice. However, during each run the `list1` will always have one item and the `list2` could have multiple items or single item that I'd like as values.

How could I approach adding the key and potentially multiple values to it?

After some deliberation, Kasramvd's second option seems to work well for this scenario:

`dictionary.setdefault(list1[0], []).append(list2)`

Comment: What will the potential keys look like? Can you show some code

Comment: im parsing some xml and on each key identified potentially multiple values will be found but there will always be 1 key at a time.

Comment: Do you want to extend both into one list? You need to add some input and expected output as it is not clear what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment all you need is assigning the second list as a value to only item of first list.

```
d = {}
d[list1[0]] = list2
```

And if you want to preserve the values for duplicate keys you can use `dict.setdefault()` in order to create value of list of list for duplicate keys.

```
d = {}
d.setdefault(list1[0], []).append(list2)
```

Comment: this doesnt seem to add all items from `list2`. Ill amend my question to include the above and results.

Comment: Ok it seems your second option has done the trick. The first one didnt work as expected, only adding hte first im in the second list.